# Exchange from field in iso format when ø character in name

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, iso

I have setup a forward connector on Exchange (2010 SP2) named (f.e.) target.domain.no. The forward record points to a Windows Server SMTP Server (EMSERVER).

Now I see in that emails that have the ø character (or other Norwegian chars) in the email address, the format of the from field in the EML file in the drop folder of the EMSERVER is in iso. But only for senders with those specific chars in the name.

For example:
Daniel Løvik<Løvik@domain.no> will be displayed in the EML as 
`From: Daniel L=F8vik?= <mhl@adeb.no>`

Daniel Test<test@domain.no> will be displayed in the EML as
`From: Daniel Frins <test@domain.no>`.

I'd like to have a situation where there is no transformation to ISO.

Comment: Correction, the first from field is formatted like:
From: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Daniel_L=F8vik?= <lovik@domain.no>

Comment: Are you asking about non-ASCII characters in the name or the local-part of the email address?

Comment: I fixed the incorrect formatting of your question. I didn't change the content. If the content is incorrect, then click on the [edit](http://serverfault.com/posts/747085/edit) link to fix it.

Comment: First thing I would do is patch the server. Exchange 2010 SP2 is no longer supported. Get it to Exchange 2010 SP3, then install the latest rollup. Then test again to see whether that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the process behind the described process uses Outlook to convert the EML to MSG. That process uses the outlook object model (not interop) for this conversion. And using Outlook 2010 for that conversion results in issues.

The solution was to install Outlook 2013.

Thanks all for the help.

br,
Daniel